# Deploying elasticsearch with express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, elasticsearch, heroku

I have developed a search engine app using express js and elastic search. Everything is working normally on localhost but when I deploy it on Heroku only express app gets deployed and elastic search client runs on localhost. So how can I deploy both of them together?

Answer (score 0):

Simply speaking you will have to ssh into Heroku server and install an instance of elasticsearch there which is impossible if you're using free tier of Heroku. Other solution might be finding a cloud elasticsearch provider and update configs in your app to connect to it

Comment: Is there any free cloud ElasticSearch provider available, as the project which I am developing is very small scale?

Comment: I found one here, may be it's enough for your app https://bonsai.io